# Conditional copy elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to copy elements from one numpy array to another while also checking condition e.g. if an element of B > 1.
So, array A will be:

```
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, [4, 5], None],
       [None, None, None]])
```

and array B:

```
array([[0, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

I need array C to be

```
array([[None, [2], [2]],
       [[2], [2, 4, 5], None],
       [None, None, None]])
```

What is the most efficient way of doing that avoiding loops?

Comment: Why are you using arrays for this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: How can you build array A? In my tests, A[1,1] reads either `list([4,5])` if a Python list or `array([4,5])` if a numpy array. What it is supposed to b? And why don't you use Python lists here?

Comment: @Serge. Make an array with dtype=object

Comment: @MadPhysicist: it displays as `..., list([4,5]),...` on my Python 3.6. I understand that dtype has to be object to store `None` values. I just wonder what type OP wants for `A[1,1]`

Comment: @Lara. Arrays are fundamentally for holding blocks of homogenous data. Just because they can hold arbitrary data does not mean that they are particularly well suited to the task. Another way to think of it is that you really won't get much benefit from numpy operations here because your final append happens in Python anyway. You may as well commit to Python at that point: don't be afraid of couple of for loops. Stick them in a function if you don't want to see them.

Comment: @Serge. Good point. I had automatically made the conversion in my head, without reading carefully. Without some code at least showing the inputs and a `for` loop solution, I'm not actually sure that the question makes sense.

Comment: @Lara. Please clarify by showing how you made the input arrays, and what your for loops look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
a = np.array([None, [1,2], None])
b = np.array([0,1,2])
np.where(b>0, a, b)
>>array([None, 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

*Alternative* - If you want to modify in place, you can also use a boolean mask:

```
a = np.array([None, [1,2], None])
b = np.array([0,1,2])
m = b > 0
a[m] = b[m]
>>array([None, 1, 2], dtype=object)
```

Sidenote: arrays are not the best thing for that kind of data (see comments)

Comment: +1.  Now, is there a version of this that will insert-in-place?  In other words, for efficiency, rather than `a = np.where(b>0, a, b)`, I'd like to just use a version that copies b in to a where the condition is true.

Comment: Added alternative in answer